# Sharing image via Facebook Share Dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I made a Facebook app for this Share Dialog to share images from my web application but whenever I load the page I get this error:

```
Uncaught: h message: "invalid version specified"
```

I tried to resolve this issue reading some older posts here but nothing works (tried to provide parameters in `js.src`, used `all.js` instead of `sdk.js`). Here is the code right after the body tag:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '224188011327825',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : '2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

And code in external file (Rails' application.js):

```
function shareFBImage() {
    var imageUrl = document.getElementById("post-image").src;
    FB.init({ appId: '224188011327825', status: true, cookie: true });
    FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'share',
            name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
            href: $(location).attr('href'),
            link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
            picture: imageUrl,
            caption: '',
            description: ''
        },
            function (response) {
                if (response && response.post_id) {
                    alert('success');
                } else {
                    alert('error');
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved; I initialized `FB.init` second time here:

`FB.init({ appId: '224188011327825', status: true, cookie: true });`